# How to print a text using list and combining more list components to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, stack

**Why it is not printing ??**

Actually, I am a python beginner and I was learning stacks in python and got stuck here
HOW TO FIX IT ??

```
text = ""
def func():
     stack=["asd", "qwe"]
     text=stack[1]
     text=text+stack[0]

func()
print(text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing global variables within a function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564669/changing-global-variables-within-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

when you are defining a function the variable inside the function is not accessible to the outside of the function so you have to return the variable you want to update. u can use `print(func())` or `text=func()` or `print(text)`

```
text = ""
def func():
     stack=["asd", "qwe"]
     text=stack[1]
     text=text+stack[0]
     return  text

text=func()
print(text)
```

**output**

```
qweasd
```