# Python How to Pass string to function by reference

Tags: python, string, reference, arguments

```
def foo(arg1,arg2,arg3)
   arg3="new_value"
   return arg1+arg2
arg3=""
foo(1,2,arg3)
```

And I still get "" in arg3 after calling foo(). I want to get arg3=="new_value".
How do I do that?

Comment: you need to use a `return` to bring value outside function. or `global`

Comment: All arguments are passed by value.

Comment: See [changing global variables within a function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51564669/3890632)

Comment: Objects are always "passed by reference", as far as that description even makes sense in Python. However, strings are *immutable* so it's entirely impossible to do what you want.

Comment: Note that it's very important to say whether you expect ``arg3=="new_value"`` to work because the string *assigned to* ``arg3`` was mutated or because ``arg3`` was assigned a new object.

Answer (score 2):

Python always receives parameters by value, so assigning a new value to a parameter variable inside the body of a function won't affect the caller.

If the value is *mutable*, then *mutating* it inside the body of the function *will* affect the caller, but strings are immutable (there's no method you can call on a string that will change its contents, only return a new string).

In general, the way to approach the situation you describe is to simply return multiple values:

```
def foo(arg1,arg2,arg3)
   arg3="new_value"
   return arg1+arg2, arg3
arg3=""
_, arg3 = foo(1, 2, arg3)
```

If you need an immutable argument to be mutable, though, an easy workaround (that doesn't involve using `global`) is to wrap it in a mutable container, like a list:

```
def foo(arg1,arg2,arg3)
   arg3[0]="new_value"
   return arg1+arg2
arg3=[""]
foo(1,2,arg3)
# arg3[0] is now "new_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate an outside-function variable, you either have to `return` it, or use it as a `global` variable:

`return`

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3):

    arg3 = "new_value"
    return arg1 + arg2, arg3

arg3 = ""
first_return, arg3 = foo(1, 2, arg3)
```

`global`

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    
    global arg3
    arg3 = "new_value"
    return arg1 + arg2

arg3 = ""
first_return = foo(1, 2)
```